# Trying to do Hibernate Update - can someone point me in the right direction?

Tags: hibernate

I was trying to follow the example in the document
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3 ... tch-direct

But get the following error in my server log:

> **SEVERE: org.hibernate.QueryException: query must begin with SELECT or FROM: update [update hibernate.TbUser u set u.vcUserName = :userName, u.vcUserPsw = :userPsw, u.vcUserFirstName = :firstName, u.vcUserLastName = :lastName, u.vcUserMiddleName = :middleName, u.vcEmailAddress = :email, u.vcPhoneNumber = :phone, u.dtTerminatedDate = :termDate, u.dtHireDate = :hireDate, u.dtUpdTime = :updTime, u.iUpdUserId = :userId where iUserId = :id]**

This suggests I need to start the query with `SELECT` or `FROM`, however the example uses `Update` in the update query, so I do not understand what the problem is.

Can anyone show me to an example of how to do an `Update`???
The documentation apparently does not.
Thanks.

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
public int updateUser( String userName, String passwd, String firstName, String middleName, 
        String lastName, String email, String phone, Date termDate, Date hireDate, int id )
{
    int status = 0;
    try {
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String cmd = "update TbUser u set u.vcUserName = :userName, "+
                "u.vcUserPsw = :userPsw, u.vcUserFirstName = :firstName, "+
                "u.vcUserLastName = :lastName, u.vcUserMiddleName = :middleName, "+
                "u.vcEmailAddress = :email, u.vcPhoneNumber = :phone, "+
                "u.dtTerminatedDate = :termDate, u.dtHireDate = :hireDate, "+
                "u.dtUpdTime = :updTime, u.iUpdUserId = :userId where iUserId = :id";
        Query q = session.createQuery( cmd );
        q.setString("userName", userName);
        q.setString("userPsw", passwd);
        q.setString("firstName", firstName);
        q.setString("middleName", middleName);
        q.setString("lastName", lastName);
        q.setString("email", email);
        q.setString("phone", phone);
        q.setDate("termDate", termDate);
        q.setDate("hireDate", hireDate);
        q.setDate("updTime", new Date());
        q.setInteger("id", id);
        status = q.executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        status = -1;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=944696), looks like you need to include the antlr*.jar in your classpath and use a different parser, `org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory`.

Try using that library and see how you go.